# Why do different elements end up different sizes, even with the same width & height?

Tags: html, css, input, size

Why are some elements slightly bigger and smaller then other elements? For example a div set to width:200 and height:35, is the same height as a input box with width:196 and height:29.

**Example:**

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:35px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

input {
  width:200px;
  height:35px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

#inp1 {
  opacity:.5;
 }
```

```html
<h3>Both set to width:200px and height:35px</h3>
<div>DIV</div>
<input placeholder='Input'>
<br>
<h3>Overlapping comparison</h3>
<div>
  <input id='inp1'>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied your code and they look identical on my comp. Input is one pixel off to the right of the input field and one pixel down. That is the only difference I see between the two. Sorry if I misunderstood something here. Maybe you don't have box-sizing: border-box; set.

Comment: Because browsers apply their own styles to HTML elements. Each browser has its own [***default style sheet***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html). You need to override these styles with your own, as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, an input element has certain css-properties such as outline-width, padding, etc. Try setting them all to 0px and try again :)

Answer (score 1):

Inputs have a default `padding`. Set the `padding` to `0` and you'll see that both `div` and `input` will be rendered with the same dimensions!

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:35px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

input {
  width:200px;
  height:35px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding: 0;
}

#inp1 {
  opacity:.5;
 }
```

```html
<h3>Both set to width:200px and height:35px</h3>
<div>DIV</div>
<input placeholder='Input'>
<br>
<h3>Overlapping comparison</h3>
<div>
  <input id='inp1'>
</div>
```

Comment: it also helps to use box-sizing:border-box across all elements on a web page

Comment: What does that do?